# How to narrow down to specific contrasts with lsmeans

Tags: r, lsmeans

I would like to use contrast() with an lsmeans object to perform some specific planned comparisons, but I cannot find a method to perform the comparisons I want. I want to compare whether one factor has an effect at either of two factor levels. For example, in the below I would like to compare whether A,C differs to B,C, and whether A,D is different to B,D. I do not want to compare whether A, C is different to B, D or different to A, D, etc.

```
fac_one <- c(rep("A", 200), rep ("B", 200))
fac_two <- rep(c("C", "D"), 200)

dats <- data.frame(fac_one= c(rep("A", 200), rep ("B", 200)),
                   fac_two= rep(c("C", "D"), 200))

dats$y <- NA

dats$y[dats$fac_one=="A" & dats$fac_two=="C"] <- 
  rnorm(100, mean=0.9, sd=1)
dats$y[dats$fac_one=="B" & dats$fac_two=="C"] <- 
  rnorm(100, mean=0.9, sd=1)

dats$y[dats$fac_one=="A" & dats$fac_two=="D"] <- 
  rnorm(100, mean=0.6, sd=1)
dats$y[dats$fac_one=="B" & dats$fac_two=="D"] <- 
  rnorm(100, mean=1.4, sd=1)

mod <- lm(y ~ fac_one*fac_two, data = dats)
Anova(mod)

lsmns <- lsmeans(mod, ~fac_one*fac_two)
#currently does many contrasts that I do not want to do
contrast(lsmns)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
contrast(lsmns, “pairwise”, by = “fac_two”)
```

It’s in the documentation

Comment: `fac_two` needs to be in quotes, I believe.

Comment: Wait a minute, though, you're not just any @rvl, you're the package author, yes? It's a great package, I love it, thanks so much!

Comment: Yup, I am. Glad you like the package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `|` instead of `*` to tell `emmeans` to separate them into groups based on that factor. You can then use `pairs` to get pairwise comparisons within each group. Also note that both the package and the function have been renamed in the latest versions to `emmeans` from `lsmeans`, though this functionality is in the older versions as well.

```
> library(emmeans)
> lsmns <- emmeans(mod, ~fac_one|fac_two)
> pairs(lsmns)
fac_two = C:
 contrast estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 A - B      -0.044 0.142 396 -0.309  0.7574 

fac_two = D:
 contrast estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 A - B      -0.974 0.142 396 -6.848  <.0001
```

PS. Nice reproducible example. :)